# Mongoose: Find, update, save - No error, changes in save callback too, but not in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In MongoDB, I wanted to update a document(not using **update** command) after finding it.

```
    User.findOne({"userId": userId}, {_id: false}, function(err, user) {

        user.userStatus = "inactive";

        user.save(function(err, updatedUser) {
            console.log("user updated", updatedUser.userStatus);
            callback(err, updatedUser);
        });

    });
```

Even though the property is a not a nested child, I tried using `user.markModified("userStatus")` . It was not working.

Comment: MongoDB update document through `_id`, so if you don't select `_id` field, MongoDB can not update any document because of no match.

Answer (score 3):

After digging deep into the function params, I found that we shouldn't exclude **`{ _id: false }`** from the result, if we need to update the document.